# c++ bug in uniform real distribution?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, clang, standard-library

I'm trying to use `std::uniform_real_distribution<float>(a, b)` to generate random floats, and I found a case where the output is equal to the upper limit `b`. According to:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_real_distribution
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution
this shouldn't happen.

With both `gcc-4.9.2` and `clang-3.5.0`, the following crashes for me:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <random>

int main() {
    float a = 1.0f;
    float b = 1.001f;
    size_t seed = 293846;
    size_t n = 9830;
    std::mt19937 rg(seed);
    std::uniform_real_distribution< float > u(a, b);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        float v = u(rg);
        if (not (v < b)) {
            std::cerr << "error: i=" << i
                      << " v=" << std::scientific << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits< double >::max_digits10) << v
                      << " b=" << b << std::endl;
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

The output I see is:

```
error: i=9829 v=1.00100004673004150e+00 b=1.00100004673004150e+00
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is this a bug with the Standard Library? Am I missing something?

**Edit**. While not an exact duplicate, the issue raised in this question is indeed covered by the answer to the other question referenced here.

Most informative about the status of this issue is the LLVM bug thread here: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18767

Comment: Not every day I see a C programmer using `not` instead of `!` ;)

Comment: @Lapshin: I'm of split opinion on the practice. On the one hand the keywords logicals are nice, but on the other hand a decade of not using them makes them seem out of place.

Comment: @Hurkyl i am not against, actually like here it's more readable, but still.

Comment: A case reproduced on my machine. A good question indeed!

Comment: :) how about spaces inside template parameters, a relic of `>>` parsing :)

Comment: @MateiDavid I am actually too young to got used to that ugly spacing, praise c++11)

Comment: This is another manifestation of the `generate_canonical<float>` problem.

Answer (score 0):

While `[rand.dist.uni.real]` mandates the uniform distribution on the half-open interval of *real numbers*, it doesn't contain any language regarding how those should be rounded to floating point representations.

So from the information I could find, it may very well be legal (and *required*) for a conforming implementation to produce floating point numbers that compare equal to the upper bound.

Comment: I like your answer, but still, standart says `a <= x < b`, and that part keeps me from agreing with you...